# Matlab: delete struct element from GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, tags, uicontrol

The results of my matlab program are shown in a GUI in some textedits created dynamically based on the number of results, the user can edit those results and save it into a struct by pressin a button (by callback function).

Now im trying to give the option of deleting the textedits, my idea was to make a small button with an "X" next to each textedits but im having hard time to pass the index of the button pressed and its respective textedit to the callback function which supposed to delete the edits.

Also at the moment I have no idea how to dynamically tag each element

Example of the GUI:
%the program found 5 results

> ```
> [X] [result 1] 
> [X] [result 2]
> [X] [result 3] 
> [X] [result 4]
> [X] [result 5]
>
> [OK]
> ```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Use the `'Tag'` property of the pushbutton `uicontrol` object.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

in the definition of the Pushbutton:

```
'Tag', strcat('Result',num2str(i))
```

since the edits are generated in a *for* loop

in the callback get the tag through the *object_handle* of the button that triggered the callback.